# Display Firebase Data with React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

Hello everyone i am new on React Native and i am trying to display some data i am fetching from firebase

Here is the data Json Shema i want to fetch 
[image: Data Json]

For now i just wrote a redux action creator like this

```
    export const employeesFetch = () =>{
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();

    return(dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
        .on('value', snap => {
            dispatch({type: EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snap.val()});
        })
    };
};
```

Here a screen Capture of my console : 
[image: Console]

Now how can i have access to each employee of each user and display each properties of them ? 
Thanks you for your help ..

Comment: What do you see when you log the respective `state` part? This question sounds like it is only about parsing/handling a basic object, and not really about react native, firebase or redux...?

Comment: when i log state part i see " undefined " , how can we handle or parse object with react native ?

Comment: Dealing with an object in React native doesn't work differently from doing it in JavaScript. Where does the payload end up? Which state will it change? Can you log that's component's state?

Comment: You've written an action creator and, judging from the `EmployeeReducer.js` in your console screenshot, also a reducer. In the reducer, you'll now need to update your state accordingly. If your initial state is `undefined`, it is probably not initialized at all - you can use a default parameter in your reducer to initialize it with an empty object. Once you've got that, use `connect` to map your state to properties where needed and you'll be able to access your data.